# trouble with a line in Opencv 2.4.5 and VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I want to draw a line on the output from my web cam.  This is what I have tried so far.

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;
Point p1 = Point(100,80);
Point p2 = Point(200,80);
int main(){
    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(1){
        cap>>image;
        imshow("window", image);
        line(image,p1,p2,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
        waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code displays the image first and then draws a line - it won't work, you have to draw the line first.

```
while(1){
    cap>>image;
    line(image,p1,p2,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    imshow("window", image);
    waitKey(33);
}
```